# Different between GA avg time on page vs. avg visit duration

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page, page-views

I'm newer to using Google Analytics, and I have a question about a page in my website I'm looking at.

For a specific page in my website, the avg. time on page is 1:08. But, when I find this page under Content > Site Content > Landing page, the avg. visit duration is 0:26.

Can someone explain the difference between these two metrics? I think I understand how avg time on page is calculated, but I don't see how it's different to avg visit duration.

If someone was to ask me how long does a user typical stay on this page before leaving to go somewhere else (whether to a different website or somewhere else within our own website), what would I say?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Average Time on Page is calculated as the average difference between
>   the request timestamp for that page and the request timestamp for the
>   next pageview that occurred within your site. If only a single page is
>   viewed during a visit, that pageview does not figure into Average Time
>   on Page, since there is no second timestamp to subtract from.
>
> Similarly, Average Visit Duration is calculated based on the timestamp
>   difference between the first and final pageviews that occurred during
>   a visit. Since the duration of the final pageview cannot be
>   calculated, Average Visit Duration as reported in GA is always
>   somewhat shorter than in actuality.
>    - Taken from http://gatipoftheday.com/average-time-on-page-average-visit-duration-and-browser-timestamps/

If you wanted to figure out how much time the user spent on the page you'd look at the Avg. time on page.