# Google Analytics: How can 'Avg time on page' stat be larger than my 'Avg visit duration' stat?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been reading some about the difference between Google Analytics "**Avg Visit Duration**" statistic and their "**Avg Time on Page**" statistic.

I've found many good answers, among them, this [one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44983/different-between-ga-avg-time-on-page-vs-avg-visit-duration).

However, even as I read these explanations of the two numbers, I'm struggling to understand how it could be that my blog site has an Avg Time on Page that is far above the Avg. Visit Duration...

My Avg. Time on Page is currently   **05:23**

My Avg. Visit Duration is currently **01:58**

Does that make any sense?  I thought that the average visit duration *has* to be larger than the average time on page, because it's a super-set of that.  I thought it's the difference in time between the first and final pageviews of a visitor, which would always be larger than the view time of a single page... What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks!